# More efficient way to extract address components

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currenty, I'm using the following code to get the country, postal code, locality and sub-locality:

```
var country, postal_code, locality, sublocality;
for (i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < results[0].address_components[i].types.length; ++j)
    {
        if (!country && results[0].address_components[i].types[j] == "country")
            country = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        else if (!postal_code && results[0].address_components[i].types[j] == "postal_code")
            postal_code = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        else if (!locality && results[0].address_components[i].types[j] == "locality")
            locality = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        else if (!sublocality && results[0].address_components[i].types[j] == "sublocality")
            sublocality = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
    }
}
```

That's unsatisfactory. Is there any other way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (typeof Object.keys == 'function')
    var length = function(x) { return Object.keys(x).length; };
else
    var length = function() {};

var location = {};      
for (i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; ++i)
{
    var component = results[0].address_components[i];
    if (!location.country && component.types.indexOf("country") > -1)
        location.country = component.long_name;
    else if (!location.postal_code && component.types.indexOf("postal_code") > -1)
        location.postal_code = component.long_name;
    else if (location.locality && component.types.indexOf("locality") > -1)
        location.locality = component.long_name;
    else if (location.sublocality && component.types.indexOf("sublocality") > -1)
        location.sublocality = component.long_name;

    // nothing will happen here if `Object.keys` isn't supported!
    if (length(location) == 4)
        break;
}
```

This is the most suitable solution for me. It may help someone too.

Answer (score 20):

You could use the following function to extract any address component:

```
function extractFromAdress(components, type){
    for (var i=0; i<components.length; i++)
        for (var j=0; j<components[i].types.length; j++)
            if (components[i].types[j]==type) return components[i].long_name;
    return "";
}
```

To extract the info you call:

```
var postCode = extractFromAdress(results[0].address_components, "postal_code");
var street = extractFromAdress(results[0].address_components, "route");
var town = extractFromAdress(results[0].address_components, "locality");
var country = extractFromAdress(results[0].address_components, "country");
```

etc...

Comment: locality and route no longer works, do you have a solution?

Comment: Thank you for the solution, i've revised it and worked for me. 
this.editedItem.Province = this.extractFromAdress(data.results[0].address_components, "administrative_area_level_1");
this.editedItem.District = this.extractFromAdress(data.results[0].address_components, "administrative_area_level_2");
this.editedItem.Neighborhood =  this.extractFromAdress(data.results[0].address_components, "administrative_area_level_4");

Answer (score 18):

My one-liner using a functional approach and `map`, `filter`, and ES2015:

```
/**
 * Get the value for a given key in address_components
 * 
 * @param {Array} components address_components returned from Google maps autocomplete
 * @param type key for desired address component
 * @returns {String} value, if found, for given type (key)
 */
function extractFromAddress(components, type) {
    return components.filter((component) => component.types.indexOf(type) === 0).map((item) => item.long_name).pop() || null;
}
```

Usage:

```
const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
const address_components = place["address_components"] || [];

const postal_code = extractFromAddress(address_components, "postal_code");
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Very effective

Comment: very talented ans.it is helpful

Answer (score 9):

You can shorten it to

```
var country, postal_code, locality, sublocality;
for (i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; ++i) {
    var component = results[0].address_components[i];
    if (!sublocality && component.types.indexOf("sublocality") > -1)
        sublocality = component.long_name;
    else if (!locality && component.types.indexOf("locality") > -1)
        locality = component.long_name;
    else if (!postal_code && component.types.indexOf("postal_code") > -1)
        postal_code = component.long_name;
    else if (!country && component.types.indexOf("country") > -1)
        country = component.long_name;
}
```

Or are you trying to get a better formatted result? Then please show us your query.

Comment: No, I just need the specific components.

Comment: Do I even need to check if the variables are undefined? With other words: Is it possible that there are multiple components in one result with equal types?

Comment: I've no idea whether that happens or not, but checking for not falsy values saves us from searching for already found types and therefore should be a littlebit faster.

Answer (score 3):

I did it like this:

```
placeParser = function(place){
  result = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++){
    ac = place.address_components[i];
    result[ac.types[0]] = ac.long_name;
  }
  return result;
 };
```

then i just use

```
parsed = placeParser(place)
parsed.route
```

Answer (score 2):

I really believe that [user1429980](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1429980/user1429980) answer above deserves more recognition. It works really well. My answer is based on his function. I've added a few examples to better illustrate how to search the JSON object using the code user1429980 provided:

`//searches object for a given key and returns the key's value`

`extractFromObject (object, key) {
   return object.filter((component) => component.types.indexOf(key) 
   === 0).map((item)=>item.long_name).pop() || null;
}`

---

**Example 1:** Google's reverseGeocode API with longitude and latitude set at 43.6532,79.3832 (Toronto, Ontario, Canada):

`var jsonData = {} //object contains data returned from reverseGeocode API`

`var city = extractFromObject(jsonData.json.results[0].address_components, 'locality');`

`console.log(city); //Output is Toronto`

---

Example 2: Google's Places API with place ID set to ChIJE9on3F3HwoAR9AhGJW_fL-I (Los Angeles, CA, USA):

`var jsonData = {} //object contains data returned from Google's Places API`

`var city = extractFromObject(jsonData.json.result.address_components, 'locality');`

`console.log(city); //Output is Los Angeles`

Answer (score 2):

Using `lodash`

```
const result = _.chain(json.results[0].address_components)
  .keyBy('types[0]')
  .mapValues('short_name')
  .value()
```

Answer (score 1):

Visitors using underscore.js can easily convert the `address_components` array in the geocode response into an object literal:

```
var obj = _.object( 
    _.map(results[0].address_components, function(c){ 
        return  [c.types[0], c.short_name] 
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made function before that extracts a list of values given a list of place types:

```
const getValue = function(data, types=[]){
/* used by results taken from Geocoder.geocode api */
const values = data.reduce((values, address) => {
    return address.address_components.reduce((values2, component) => {
        if(component.types.reduce((result, type) => result || types.indexOf(type) > -1, false))
            values2.push(component.long_name);
        return values2
    }, []);

    if(buff.length)
        return [...values, ...buff];
    return values;
}, []).filter(
    (value, index, self) => {
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    }
);
```

}